# Google Play Console Main Store Listing for Wear OS

Tags: wear-os

[image]

> Your app’s Play Store listing provided a non-valid Wear OS screenshot which is framed within the device. A valid Wear OS screenshot must include the full-frame image of the app interface.

To those who have successfully rolled out a Wear OS app, would you please tell me what Google is trying to say.  Thanks!

Edit:
I have taken Yuri's advise have uploaded the 384px by 384px image below for the Wear OS section and created another release. Now, I'm just waiting for Google's feedback. Thanks, Yuri

[image]

Second Edit:
The image above fixed my issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/62576) for more information.

Comment: Thanks to this excellent new policy now I cannot see the boundary of the app area. I went through recently with the same thing, first I added transparent mask, which also failed. I simply had the emulator's bezel around the app area. Not sure what's wring with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9866151#zippy=%2Cscreenshots

- Upload screenshots with a minimum size of 384 x 384 pixels, and with
  a 1:1 aspect ratio.
- Provide screenshots showing only your app
  interface. Screenshots must demonstrate the actual in-app or in-game
  experience, focusing on the core features and content so users can
  anticipate what the app or game experience will be like.
- Don’t frame
  your screenshots in a Wear OS hardware device.
- Don’t include
  additional text, graphics, or backgrounds in your Wear OS screenshots
  that are not a part of your app's interface.
- Don’t include
  transparent backgrounds or masking.

Make sure the one on the left does not have a transparent background, prefer a flat black background instead.

Also the one of the right shouldn't have a device in the picture, it should just be the circle of the screen without a frame.

Comment: Hi Yuri! I edited my post to include a 800px by 1000px image of my watch. I had to make background white to show my watch which is mainly a black image. Is that what you are suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: No, did you read the doc I linked to?

    Upload screenshots with a minimum size of 384 x 384 pixels, and with a 1:1 aspect ratio....

Rest of it in the body.

Comment: I tried uploading a 384px by 384px with nothing but the image of my watch and I got "Your app's Play Store listing provided a non-valid Wear OS screenshot aspect such as 1:1 for circular and square screenshots, and 4:5 for rectangular screenshots"

Comment: For my latest attempt, I went to Google Play and downloaded the watch images of Wear OS by Google and put my own image and change the background to a lighter color for clarity.  That's the last image on my post. I'm waiting for the results now.

Comment: Look at the images here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ee.schimke.wear.soyted&hl=en&gl=US which follow the policy.

Comment: "Don’t include transparent backgrounds or masking.". But masking with black is OK :P

Comment: it really had to be black or can be gray or other color? black with black looks awful like on your samples