# How to satisfy "non-valid Wear OS screenshot which is framed within the device" Wear OS watch face policy violation?

Tags: android, wear-os, watchface, policy-violation

I adjusted the COVID-19 data checkbox in my Wear OS watch face's play store settings. After submission I got an unexpected policy violation of `"Your app’s Play Store listing provided a non-valid Wear OS screenshot which is framed within the device. A valid Wear OS screenshot must include the full-frame image of the app interface."`

The whole round circle of the emulator is inside all 5 screenshots of my app, so I have the full-frame of the app, so the only explanation for this could be that the emulator little bezel was also visible around the app view area. So I wasted some hours and masked out the bezel and anything except the app screen with a transparent color.

Now I got another policy violation: `"Your Wear OS screenshots include transparent backgrounds or masking."`.

Until round PNGs are invented *there must be something around the app area*. I obviously opted for a transparent color, because I don't know if the user who browses the listing has their phone in dark mode or light mode. I assume if foolishly I decided on either white or black color masking, that would be a masking violation. How am I supposed to solve this? The email address of the policy violations are no-reply email addresses, so I cannot get help from there.

I guess the policy could be this guideline WO-F2. https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/wear-app-quality#better

"The app must mention Wear OS in its Google Play Store listing and contain at least one screenshot that depicts the Wear OS app experience. Provide screenshots showing only your app interface. Don’t place your screenshots within device frames, or include additional text, graphics, or backgrounds that are not part of the interface of your app. Upload screenshots with a 1:1 aspect ratio. For more information, see Add preview assets to showcase your app."

Due to the roundness of wearables it's absolutely impossible to not have any background around my watch face app.

Here are my two watch faces with this violation:

1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.csaba.vfdwatchface
2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.csaba.complicationflowerwatchface

---

**Attention against closing**: although that [Google Play Console Main Store Listing for Wear OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784381/google-play-console-main-store-listing-for-wear-os) happens to answers my question, it does not have the specific policy violation message in the title, or EVEN IN THE TEXT. It's only on the screenshot, so no wonder I haven't found it when I searched for my problem before posting my issue. If we close my entry, I can 100% GUARANTEE you that others will open up similar entries over time, because they won't find that other issue either. Consider that please before voting for closing.

Comment: "Due to the roundness of wearables" -- not all Wear OS devices are round. The vast majority are round, but there are some square ones (Oppo Watch and a Polar model, to name two off the top of my head). "How am I supposed to solve this?" -- FWIW, I believe that we used black, though in our case it's an app (not a watch face) and the app UI has a dark theme. All that being said though... [this question is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare so if I mask with black that satisfies them? Worth the try...

Comment: After initially getting this same complaint, we submitted JPEGs that had our app content on a black background, and they were accepted. YMMV.

Comment: Ok, I re-edited and black masked the screenshots, submitted for review and soon I'll see if there's satisfaction.

Comment: About being off-topic, I read that entry and in case of Play Store the email is coming from a no reply access. So also my first choice is usually get help on vendor support or forums. Only after that I come here, and our exchange proves that it was worth it. I'm sure I'll solve this with the help of the community. Otherwise I can hide in my cave as a hermit and SO can slump into irrelevance

Comment: Also I predict that as more and more devs will refresh their apps my issue here will pop up for others as well.

Comment: "Only after that I come here" -- note that there are other places on the Internet for getting support, such as Reddit, that have different rules and may be more amenable to questions about dealing with app store policies and rejections.

Comment: @CommonsWare Good news, masking with black went through! If you add it as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: @CommonsWare If my question was removed I'd turn to Quora or Reddit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Console Main Store Listing for Wear OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784381/google-play-console-main-store-listing-for-wear-os)

Comment: @YuriSchimke although that SO question answers my question, but it does not have the specific policy violation message in the title, or EVEN IN THE TEXT. It's just in a freakin screenshot. No wonder I haven't found it when I searched for my problem before posting. Therefore I want to resist closing, unless the other question would mention at least "non-valid Wear OS screenshot" or something. In its form the other question is just generic textually.

Comment: Fair point, it wasn't my question, but you are right, and I'll suggest an edit to include that. I didn't mean to cause offense, just linking these.

Comment: @YuriSchimke I know, no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dupe of [Google Play Console Main Store Listing for Wear OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71784381/google-play-console-main-store-listing-for-wear-os/71792690#71792690)

You need a non-transparent background, preferably black.

I use fastlane for publishing my app, so I wrote this plugin for it's screenshots that automates this.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/20054

But you can do this manually with a photo editor, since the Android Studio screenshots either have transparent or a device frame.

Comment: I was afraid to add any colored background because that's masking. But when I used black it passed the review.

Comment: That other issue does not have the policy violation in the title or in the body either, only on a screenshot. In this form others won't find it either when searching for "non-valid Wear OS screenshot" or other combinations.

Comment: @CsabaToth how can you use black background if your app has dark backround. i am not sure what is the solution here? I have taken screenshots directly from the watch and uploaded without amending. thats how google is describing.

Comment: @Emil Exactly! Since the watch background is black, and I'm masking with black the user now doesn't really know where is the boundary of the screen really on the screenshots. But that's the only way now. I could maybe draw a grey circle hairline maybe, but I won't "poke the bear" with a stick any more, I'm just super relieved that the submission went through.

Comment: @CsabaToth i have tried with a grey background and it was accepted. I think that doesnt have to be black but any other not light color

Comment: @Emil That's a great info! When I'll have time I'll resubmit that way. So some dark grey.